# Include filename in MIME base64 encoding

Tags: mime

When encoding a picture, say, into a MIME base64 string, is there a standard way of also including its filename, or at least a suggested filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.jpg"`. The `Content-Type` header can also contain a `name=` attribute although it is not recommended.

I am assuming email, but IIRC the same goes for HTTP.

Comment: I'm actually dealing with neither email nor HTTP, but rather URIs, feed directly to the browser. That doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: If all you have is bare base64 data then no, there is no way to pass in metadata, unless the image format itself has provisions for this.

Comment: Do you know of image formats that have provisions for name metadata?

Comment: Room for a separate question, perhaps.  But it seems that the FlashPix extension for EXIF has something of the sort; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format#FlashPix_extensions